# issue with getting result object of mysql query into a function

Tags: php, mysql, function

I have a function to process info from a database. This is called multiple times in a page. And I don't want to query the database every time. So I put the query outside. If I do that, the function doesn't work. I know this can be done because, there was a similar question somewhere in SO. But that addressed a different situation. I don't know what is wrong here. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

If I put all this code into a separate test file including the conn file and query, it works. But in my main page, where I have the functions.php included first, then conn.php and then the query and then the display code called by js fadein event, the $result refuses to work inside the function

EDIT : This code has been cleaned up as per comments received (globals replaced with variables passed to the function and variable names rationalised)

```
function total($item,$result,$val){
    global $totRate;
    while($getRates=$result->fetch_assoc()){    
    $gotItem= strtolower(preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/',"",$getRates['item']));
    $gotItem=str_replace(array("_"," ","/"),"",$gotItem);

    if($item==$gotItem){
          $rate= $getRates['rate'];
          $totRate=$val*$rate;
        return $totRate;
        }
    }
}
```

The Result Call PHP file

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM rates ORDER BY item";
$result = $orderdb->query($query)

if (isset($_POST[$itemname]) && !empty($_POST[$itemname])) {
    $val=$_POST[$itemname];
    total($itemname);
    echo $totprate;
} else {
    echo "0";
}
```

Comment: Can you show code of how you are calling the `total` function? Is this php file declared as a class or does it just do the query and contain the total function?

Comment: @xanT Please see the last snippet saying The Result Call. The total() function is called there. The php file is not declared as a class it just does the query and and contains the total function

Comment: I would suggest you stop making functions which pull in everything from global space and that you start using variable names which make it clearer what you're trying to do. `$gotitem` for example would read better as `$gotItem` or `$got_item`. Then the implication from the words is that it's a boolean, but you're using it as a string. Is `$getratess` the feminine form of `$getrate`? Who can tell. `$pid` has a distinct meaning outside of your code. `$totprate` is meaningless to the casual reader. That makes it difficult for you to see the problems in your own code.

Comment: Once you have a working function, take it over to [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). There are a number of issues beyond the code not functioning.

Comment: I have edited and cleaned up the code as per moopet's suggestions....and outis, I will def try the codereview SE

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this with the assumption that your SQL is working but are having problems displaying what you want - this may help. The code below saves your `$result` variable from your query and then passes it into the `total` function as a second parameter. Previously you were returning `$totprate` from `total` but you were not saving it anywhere - it is now saved to the `$totprate` variable.

Note: I cannot see `$orderdb` anywhere in your code, I'm assuming you have that in your file and that it is working.

```
function total($item, $result){
    global $val;
    global $pid;
    global $pitem;
    global $prate;
    global $totprate;
    global $gotitem;
    global $getratess;
    // global variable for $result removed so it doesn't overwrite variable passed to function

    while($getratess=$result->fetch_assoc()){
        $gotitem= strtolower(preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/',"",$getratess['item']));
        $gotitem=str_replace(array("_"," ","/"),"",$gotitem);

        if ($item==$gotitem) {
            $pid=$getratess['id'];
            $pitem= $getratess['item'];
            $prate= $getratess['rate'];
            $totprate=$val*$prate;
            return $totprate;
        }
    }
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM rates ORDER BY item";
$result = $orderdb->query($query);

if (isset($_POST[$itemname]) && !empty($_POST[$itemname])) {
    $val=$_POST[$itemname];
    $totprate = total($val, $result); // pass itemname as first parameter and result array as second parameter and save it to the $totprate variable
    echo $totprate;
} else {
    echo "0";
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: XanT, thanks for your effort.  I have moved all globals to variables passed to the function.   However it still is not working. Btw, orderdb is part of the conn.php file which I have included at the beginning of the script. If I put all this code into a separate test file including the conn file and query, it works. But in my main page, the $result refuses to work inside the function